# Angular2: property binding not work with A-Frame entity

Tags: angular, aframe

I'm using Angular2 and [A-Frame](https://aframe.io/) to design a web application which displays virtual scene. But it seems data binding feature of Angular does not work with a-frame entity

I bind image url to [src] attribute of  entity as the following:

====>>> sim.component.html

```html
<a-scene>
    <a-entity camera look-controls position="10 0 8" rotation="0 20 0">
    </a-entity>

    <a-plane *ngFor="let item of layers; let i = index" width="10" height="6"
        src={{imageURL}} position="0 0 {{-3*i + 3}}">
    </a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

====>>> sim.component.ts

```typescript
    @Component({
        templateUrl: './sim.component.html',
        selector: 'sim-tag',
        providers: [SimService]
    })
    export class SimComponent implements OnInit {

        imageURL: string;
        layers: Object[];

        constructor(private service: SimService, private config: Configuration){}

        ngOnInit() {
            this.layers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
            this.imageURL = "http://localhost/images/test.jpg";     
        }
    }
```

When run application, I think it should generate an **a-plane** entity like

```html
<a-plane height="6" width="10"
    ng-reflect-src="http://localhost/images/test.jpg" src="http://localhost/images/test.jpg"
    ng-reflect-position="0 0 0" position="0 0 0" >
</a-plane>
```

but actually it is

```html
<a-plane height="6" width="10" 
    ng-reflect-src="http://localhost/images/test.jpg" 
    ng-reflect-position="0 0 0"  position="">
</a-plane>
```

there is no "src" and "position" attribute, hence, plane image display nothing.

I made a demo here: https://plnkr.co/edit/t6YhZy5gCzgycaYVeGrt?p=preview

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: can you get the code snippet run in the snippet editor? currently brings error

Comment: I have made a demo at https://plnkr.co/edit/t6YhZy5gCzgycaYVeGrt?p=preview

Comment: @hauca Did you find the solution of this? I've met the same problem.

Comment: No, I have not found any solution. Instead of using Angular *ngFor directive, I use javascript to append tags and attribute

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enclose the attribute you are trying to set in square brackets and prefix with `attr`.
EX: `[attr.position]="positionString"`

Answer (score 0):

I can help a litle bit but the answer is not complete i think ;-)

the a-plane uses as src an  where you define the image source..
see https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/primitives/a-plane.html#sidebar

that means your template should be a litle bit like:

```
    <div>Hello AFrame and Angular2</div>
    <div>plane images do not display</div>
    <a-scene>
     <a-assets>
    <img id="ground" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png">
  </a-assets>
    <a-entity camera look-controls position="10 0 8" rotation="0 20 0">
    </a-entity>


      <a-plane *ngFor="let item of layers; let i = index" width="10" height="6"
        src="#ground" position="0 0 {{-3*i + 3}}">
    </a-plane>


</a-scene>
```

But I expect you want the image source inside of the a-plane foreach, but the a-asset must a child of the a-scene

the plunk

https://plnkr.co/edit/YrXKnaLO5cEqy12pAkW1?p=preview

Comment: I have tried this way before but it not complete solution.        

Firstly, it just solve problem of binding image source to "src" property while problem still occur with other attribute such as "position", "rotation", etc.        

Secondly, since my real application need to set different Image URLs for different <a-plane>, therefore creating many assets respective to images is not what I expect.      

Thank your for your suggestion.